# Facebook Login Webview is blank

Tags: android, android-simple-facebook

I'm using the android-simple-facebook library to provide a login button in my Android app.  When the Facebook app is not installed on the device, I see a blank webview popup dialog instead of a login webpage.

I see this in my logs:

```
08-24 19:33:09.040  21965-22060/com.unifiapp E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
08-24 19:33:09.060  21965-21965/com.unifiapp E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
08-24 19:33:09.060  21965-21965/com.unifiapp E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider
08-24 19:33:09.750  21965-22063/com.unifiapp D/autoproxy﹕ URL in SetProxyForUrl is      https://m.facebook.com/v2.1/dialog/oauth?return_scopes=true&response_type=token&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1408933989665%7D&client_id=2131492888&default_audience=friends
```

I have set my appId in strings.xml and the manifest, I have set the correct package name and classname to match up with the app dashboard in Facebook, and have verified my key hashes are correct (I was previously using the Facebook SDK directly, when the calls were working).
I have Internet permissions in my manifest.

Comment: You might look at [resolveActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager)). The error seems to show that your device does not know which provider to use for your action/intent.

Comment: Is this something to do with SSO? May be you should disable it and try?